# "DESCRIBE" SPARQL query on Dbpedia

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia

I want to extract dbpedia data to RDF using "DESCRIBE" query.

For instance, if i type:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
DESCRIBE ?movie ?author ?genre
WHERE { 
?movie rdf:type db:Film ;
prop:author ?author ;
prop:genre ?genre .
}
LIMIT 50
OFFSET 0
```

everything works fine.

However, if i add actor and duration properties:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
DESCRIBE ?movie ?author ?genre ?actor ?duration
WHERE { 
?movie rdf:type db:Film ;
prop:author ?author ;
prop:genre ?genre;
prop:actor ?actor;
prop:duration ?duration .
}
LIMIT 50
OFFSET 0
```

I'm getting empty RDF.

Here is schema for Movie: http://schema.org/Movie

Anyone?

Comment: Can you provide the RDF input?

Comment: i'm not sure what are you asking me for. sorry, i'm kinda a new at rdf and sparql :)

Comment: Do you have a local file? Do you test your queries online against the dbpedia site?

Comment: i'm doing queries at http://dbpedia.org/sparql with "RDF/XML" results format chosen. As i said, first query returns rdf with some data while second one returns empty rdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a problem with the input. Assuming you are testing againts dbpedia through [the SPARQL web interface](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql), you can get something by

- Marking `duration` and `genre` as optional (so they are not required to be specified)
- Using `dbpprop:starring` instead of `dbpprop:actor`

So the following query

```
DESCRIBE ?movie ?author ?genre ?actor ?duration
WHERE { 
  ?movie a dbpedia-owl:Film ;
    dbpprop:author ?author ;
    dbpprop:starring ?actor .
  OPTIONAL {
   ?movie dbpprop:duration ?duration ;
     dbpprop:genre ?genre
  }
}
LIMIT 5
OFFSET 0
```

will get you [some graphs](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=DESCRIBE%20?movie%20?author%20?genre%20?actor%20?duration%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20?movie%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aFilm%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dbpprop%3aauthor%20?author%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dbpprop%3astarring%20?actor%20.%0D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20?movie%20dbpprop%3aduration%20?duration%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20dbpprop%3agenre%20?genre%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%205%0D%0AOFFSET%200&should-sponge=&format=text/x-html%2btr&timeout=0&debug=on). Also note that I think you should introduce the `http://schema.org/` prefix to use that Movie schema (but they don't appear to be used so deeply in the dbpedia dataset)

And [here](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+%3Fmovie+%3Fauthor+%3Fgenre+%3Factor+%3Fduration%0D%0AWHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++%3Fmovie+a+dbpedia-owl%3AFilm+%3B%0D%0A++++dbpprop%3Aauthor+%3Fauthor+%3B%0D%0A++++dbpprop%3Astarring+%3Factor+.%0D%0A++OPTIONAL+%7B%0D%0A+++%3Fmovie+dbpprop%3Aduration+%3Fduration+%3B%0D%0A+++++dbpprop%3Agenre+%3Fgenre%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT+50%0D%0AOFFSET+0&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on) is the result of a `SELECT` instead of `DESCRIBE` (why do you want the `DESCRIBE` result format?) - I think it makes sense.

I think I also find something interesting. If you query

```
DESCRIBE dbpparam:starring
```

You [get an interesting error message](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=%20%20DESCRIBE%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3astarring&should-sponge=&format=text/x-html%2btr&timeout=0&debug=on)

> Errornous expression for predicate
>   'http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#equivalentProperty': schema:actors

I think this is why `schema:actor` (and maybe `dbpprop:actor` too) doesn't work. It seems an error on the indexing program.

Comment: thanks, that's better now. i need "describe" result because i want to insert that rdf to sql database and use it in my RESTful service project. can i do it with "select" result format?

Comment: I think SELECT is the way to go. DESCRIBE returns data in some agent defined fashion, and as you can see this is useful when a human is exploring things, but it makes difficult for a program to do something useful with the result. The result set coming from SELECT is perfect for a SQL database

Comment: once again, just to be sure, i can use SELECT query and than import result RDF to SQL database using JENA RDF API? somehow i tought i must use DESCRIBE :)

Comment: The `DESCRIBE` output is nonstandard, and also contains unneeded information. It's useful when a human wants to examine a database, but for feeding a program you must use `SELECT`. See [`ResultSet`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/ResultSet.html) API

Comment: thanks again. however, i can't upvote your answer, 15 reputation is needed and i don't have it atm :/

Comment: @expx Don't worry about that :)